# Matching several indexes

Tags: pattern-matching

I have a large set of data in which I need to compare several samples in different tests and under varying conditions. I am looking for a way to pair and analyze these easily. As an example, lets say I have Samples (S) a, b, and c, which undergo tests (T) 1 and 2, under conditions (C) x, y and z, which output results (R) R1 and R2.

```
S   T   C   R1  R2
a   1   x   2.9
a   1   y   2.6
a   1   z   8.7
a   2   x   9.4 0.372
a   2   y   8.1 0.208
a   2   z   7.6 0.154
b   1   x   7.5
b   1   y   7.3
b   1   z   1.7
b   2   x   3.9 0.213
b   2   y   7.9 0.435
b   2   z   2.5 0.294
c   1   x   6.2
c   1   y   1.8
c   1   z   6.3
c   2   x   1.5 0.246
c   2   y   6.0 0.496
c   2   z   1.7 0.167
```

The tests have different outputs, and I need to apply specific functions depending on the test. Such as:

```
Test1[a,b] = R1a/R1b
Test2[a,b] = R1a/R2a - R1b/R2b
```

The tests should only be applied to samples with matching conditions, but each sample should be paired. So a result would be:

```
S1  S2  T   C   R
a   b   1   x   2.9/7.5
a   c   1   x   2.9/6.2
a   b   2   x   9.4/0.372-3.9/0.213
a   c   2   x   9.4/0.372-1.5/0.246
a   b   1   y   2.6/7.3
...
```

I've been trying to get this right for a while and just end up confusing myself. Anyone have a solution or suggestions? If you want an easily copyable format of the example:

```
{{S, T, C, R1, R2}, {a, 1, x, 2.9}, {a, 1, y, 2.6}, {a, 1, z, 8.7},
 {a, 2, x, 9.4, 0.372}, {a, 2, y, 8.1, 0.208}, {a, 2, z, 7.6, 0.154},
 {b, 1, x, 7.5}, {b, 1, y, 7.3}, {b, 1, z, 1.7}, {b, 2, x, 3.9, 0.213},
 {b, 2, y, 7.9, 0.435}, {b, 2, z, 2.5, 0.294}, {c, 1, x, 6.2}, {c, 1, y, 1.8},
 {c, 1, z, 6.3}, {c, 2, x, 1.5, 0.246}, {c, 2, y, 6., 0.496}, {c, 2, z, 1.7, 0.167}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure wether I understood correctly which results should be recombined but this code does the following: First the data is gathered by condition, then by test, then subsets of length 2 are generated and in the final step the numerical computation on the results is applied:

```
test1[{{a_,1,c_,R1a_},{b_,1,c_,R1b_}}]:={a,b,1,c,R1a/R1b}
test2[{{a_,2,c_,R1a_,R2a_},{b_,2,c_,R1b_,R2b_}}]:={a,b,2,c,R1a/R2a-R1b/R2b}

{{S,T,C,R1,R2},{a,1,x,2.9},{a,1,y,2.6},{a,1,z,8.7},{a,2,x,9.4,0.372},{a,2,y,8.1,0.208},{a,2,z,7.6,0.154},{b,1,x,7.5},{b,1,y,7.3},{b,1,z,1.7},{b,2,x,3.9,0.213},{b,2,y,7.9,0.435},{b,2,z,2.5,0.294},{c,1,x,6.2},{c,1,y,1.8},{c,1,z,6.3},{c,2,x,1.5,0.246},{c,2,y,6.,0.496},{c,2,z,1.7,0.167}};

GatherBy[%,#[[3]]&][[2;;]];
Flatten[GatherBy[#,{x}\[Function]x[[2]]]&/@%,1];
Flatten[Subsets[#,{2}]&/@%,1];
If[#[[1,2]]===1,test1[#],test2[#]]&/@%;
%//TableForm
```

which results in

```
a   b   1   x   0.386667
a   c   1   x   0.467742
b   c   1   x   1.20968
a   b   2   x   6.95896
a   c   2   x   19.1713
b   c   2   x   12.2123
a   b   1   y   0.356164
a   c   1   y   1.44444
b   c   1   y   4.05556
a   b   2   y   20.7814
a   c   2   y   26.8455
b   c   2   y   6.06415
a   b   1   z   5.11765
a   c   1   z   1.38095
b   c   1   z   0.269841
a   b   2   z   40.8472
a   c   2   z   39.171
b   c   2   z   -1.67624
```

This is not the result OP expected since it contains all possible subsets for a given test and condition (e.g. the third entry b,c test 1 under condition x). If there is a more involved criteria for the combination of results the step which generates the subsets in the code above needs to be replaced/refined. Using `Subsequences` instead of `Subsets` considers only ordered tuples which might be the solution OP is looking for:

```
a   b   1   x   0.386667
b   c   1   x   1.20968
a   b   2   x   6.95896
b   c   2   x   12.2123
a   b   1   y   0.356164
b   c   1   y   4.05556
a   b   2   y   20.7814
b   c   2   y   6.06415
a   b   1   z   5.11765
b   c   1   z   0.269841
a   b   2   z   40.8472
b   c   2   z   -1.67624
```

Answer (score 4):

```
data = {{"S", "T", "C", "R1", "R2"}, {a, 1, x, 2.9}, {a, 1, y, 
    2.6}, {a, 1, z, 8.7}, {a, 2, x, 9.4, 0.372}, {a, 2, y, 8.1, 
    0.208}, {a, 2, z, 7.6, 0.154}, {b, 1, x, 7.5}, {b, 1, y, 7.3}, {b,
     1, z, 1.7}, {b, 2, x, 3.9, 0.213}, {b, 2, y, 7.9, 0.435}, {b, 2, 
    z, 2.5, 0.294}, {c, 1, x, 6.2}, {c, 1, y, 1.8}, {c, 1, z, 
    6.3}, {c, 2, x, 1.5, 0.246}, {c, 2, y, 6., 0.496}, {c, 2, z, 1.7, 
    0.167}};

Grid[data, Dividers -> All, Background -> {None, 1 -> LightBlue}, 
  Alignment -> {{Center, Center, Center, ".", "."}, Center}]
```

[image]

```
t1 = {#[[1]], #2[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]], #[[4]]/#2[[4]]} &;
t2 = {#[[1]], #2[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]], #[[4]]/#[[5]] - #2[[4]]/#2[[5]]} &;
proc = If[#[[1, 2]] === 1, t1 @@ #, t2 @@ #] &;
```

`GroupBy` data by `{test, condition}` (columns 2 and 3) and process 2-subsets using `proc`:

```
data2 = Join @@  Values @ GroupBy[Rest @ data, #[[{2, 3}]] &, 
   Map[proc] @ Subsets[#, {2}] &];

Grid[Prepend[{"S1", "S2", "T", "C", "R"}]@data2, 
  Dividers -> All, Background -> {None, 1 -> LightBlue}, 
  Alignment -> {{Center, Center, Center, Center, "."}, Center}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, we can use `GatherBy`:

```
data2 == Join @@ Map[Map[proc] @ Subsets[#, {2}]&] @ GatherBy[Rest@data, #[[{2, 3}]]&]
```

> ```
>  True
> ```